# Correct URL conditions

Tags: java, android

In my app I have got EditText, where user can put a link to show photo.

In this activity I have got button, when user clicks it, he can see a website (url that he put in a EditText).

**But there is 1 problem: application can open link only when it has got "http://www.".. else app crashed**

I think that can be only 4 situations:

> 1. User puts only www.*vebsite.com* without http://
> 2. User puts corrective url like this: http://www.*website.com*
> 3. User puts only site domain like this: *website.com* without http://www.
> 4. User puts space in url (it may be mistake)

Now I have conditions like this:

```
if (String.valueOf(text_of_url).contains("www")) {
String full_url = String.valueOf(text_of_url).replace("www.", http://www.");     
}

else if (String.valueOf(text_of_url).contains(".")) { 
String full_url = String.valueOf(text_of_url).replace(" ", "");
}
```

But it works not correctly (I'm new in java).

How can I correctly do this conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(YourUrl).matches()
```

if the url is correct, this will return TRUE. Else, it will return FALSE

Try this method:

```
private boolean isURLValid(String url){
    if(Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(url).matches()){
        return true;
    }
    //Show your warning message or whatever you want
    return false;
}
```

You cannot check every possibility with if conditions.

Comment: thank you for advice! But thats looks very difficult. Is there a simple way with conditions?

Comment: @Dmitry , edited my answer. Removed part was just to show how it works. Sorry for complication.